# Windows Phone 7 Developer Tools and Existing Visual Studio 2010 Install - How?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

Microsoft's [Windows Phone 7 developer site](http://developer.windowsphone.com/windows-phone-7/) that contains the following:

```
* Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone CTP
* Windows Phone Emulator CTP
* Silverlight for Windows Phone CTP
* XNA Game Studio 4.0 CTP
```

I already have Visual Studio 2010 installed. Will the installer use my existing installation of VS2010 and add to it or will it install an Express edition alongside it? I really wouldn't want the latter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll get express with it, but you can safely ignore it. There is no option to avoid this that I've come across.

Whilst Express will install, it won't install shortcuts or interfere with your paid VS install and has minimal impact.

Comment: So there is no way to integrate the Phone 7 dev environment with an existing VS2010 install?

Comment: Yes, if you have VS2010 already installed, the tools will install into that environment.  In the current build of the tools, it will also create a Program Files entry for the Express version.  You can still use VS2010 to do your phone development and, as Trees points out, "safely ignore" the Express tools.

Comment: Very good. It's still annoying but at least it'll add to my installation rather than break it.

Comment: Talk about epic fail! Why the hell would it want to install the VS2010 Express when it can easily see that VS2010 Not-Express is installed? Talk about .. WTF?! :(  <--- /me hates extra bloat installed onto a system .. no matter how small :~~~(

Comment: @Pure Krome There's been quite a few expressions of this nature and most of us would prefer to keep things clean given the option. Fortunately it's not a heavy impact... so I wouldn't be too concerned in this case.

Comment: @Mick N - agreed - i understand that this doesn't -break- anything per-say ... but I still totally flummoxed why the MS Team who put this installer together didn't spend that wee bit more time adding a check for vs2010 *versions* instead of 'does express exist or not'. Sorry - I just don't get that. They do this type of thing for nearly every other product. To be, it's not so much about being anal/precious about having extra bloat installed, but just showing some respect and polish of the product. (cont in the next comment)....

Comment: .. continued ... But that's just IMO and .. i'm a random dev so unless I can get 100 MVP's to voice their opinion, i'm just a silent voice out here.

Be great if @Brandon Watson would chime in, in this thread - I'd like to see why they didn't/still haven't made it leverage non-express installed versions of 2010.

Comment: I would say it's like any project on a tight time frame (which WP7SDK was - and delivered). Personally I'm more inclined to give applause for delivering what matters and getting into market and not slipping on account of things that are yes, nice, but can be lived without. I agree with you, I would like to see it on the cleanup list though.

Comment: The weirdest thing for me is that when I started the Developers tools ( for Mango ) install, it stopped saying I don't have VS2010 SP1. So I installed SP1 and it still proceeded to install VS Express.