# Download Windows phone 7 development kit

Tags: windows-phone-7

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Windows Phone 7 Developer Tools and Existing Visual Studio 2010 Install - How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211419/windows-phone-7-developer-tools-and-existing-visual-studio-2010-install-how)
>   [Is it possible to install Windows Phone 7 tools in VS2010 Pro without Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021490/is-it-possible-to-install-windows-phone-7-tools-in-vs2010-pro-without-express)

Dear all,
I want to download the windows phone 7 development kit (without visual studio express 2010.) but I can't. Could you tell me where I cant download it please?. I just need the stand alone version of wp7 development kit because I installed VS 2010 professional before.

Thanks,
IHNEL.

Comment: You won't be able to do so.  It doesn't hurt your computer to have VS2010 Express and Professional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've make a google search and here is the [result on diigo.com](http://www.diigo.com/list/namgivu/windows-phone-7)

There, you can see that we can [download a standalone .iso file](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=201927) for WP7 Dev Tool

> Note: this release is also available
>   in .iso format.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please note that the ISO does not exclude VS Express, it will still install it and create the appropriate links and associations as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

The standard installer checks your system and only downloads and installs the components you need. So if you already have VS2010 Pro installed then it won't bother downloading VS2010 Express.

Comment: Actually, VS2010 Express will be installed, it's just the links to it would be created if there's another version of VS2010 already intalled.