# Windows Phone 7 Download Versions

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

For windows phone addon, do I have to install the express tools download?  There isn't any add-on for users who already have Visual Studio RTM?  I can't find that anywhere...  I don't want to have to install express tools, there's probably an option, but curious if anyone has found that alternative download anywhere.

Thanks,

Brian

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Phone 7 Developer Tools and Existing Visual Studio 2010 Install - How?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211419/windows-phone-7-developer-tools-and-existing-visual-studio-2010-install-how)

Comment: Hi Brian, it's nothing to worry about - more detail in the question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, I was miffed by that too.  Don't worry, Express and VS2010 sit side-by-side just fine and if you just use 2010 normally everything works.  Just install the tools and trust that everything will be okay.  :)